# MYSQL Query Doesnt Return

Tags: mysql, sql, timeout

I am sending a MySQL query to a remote RDS database on AWS.

```
INSERT INTO gps_data_eid_cache (eid, location_id, first_seen, last_seen)
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT eid,
             location_id,
             MIN(day_epoch)     as first_seen,
             MAX(day_epoch)        as last_seen
      FROM gps_visitation_details gvd
      GROUP BY location_id, eid
    ) as temp_1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_seen = VALUES(last_seen);
```

The query runs fine, I can see it running in the process list (via ssh to server) and then being removed once complete and I can see the records inserted into the database so I'm sure it has run successfully. However, it's like the server isn't returning a response to say it's complete so the IDE (PHP storm but have tried with table plus and raw PHP PDO) just hangs for 2 hours, at which point I get a message saying it has failed via timeout.

This has only started happening in the last couple of weeks. It also happens if I add an index or any table modification.

*Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 7,200,104 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 7,200,104 milliseconds ago.*

I recognise its hard to diagnose this with this information so please let me know what other information you require.